# Solving a cubic equation in exact terms which is the key to solving the question in picture below

Tags: roots-of-cubics

[image]

I have arrived at the formula below, I need help with solving this cubic equation for h please.

[image]

Comment: The volume equation you give has an irrational solution (and two complex ones):  that's why the problem just asked you for a numerical approximation, which you can get from something like Newton's method, or even just reading a graph.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please expand on Newton’s method? I was hoping for an algebraic rather than graphical solution. I’m not up to complex numbers yet in my study. I will edit my question to include the textbook solution.

Comment: [Please do not use images to convey textual information.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/)  You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/) to format mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at a height $z \ge 0$ the area of a horizontal section of the vase is equal to:

$$
A(z) = \left(6+2\,z\tan(30°)\right)^2
$$

at time $t \ge 0$ the volume of water in the vase is equal to:

$$
V(t) = \int_0^{h(t)} A(z)\,\text{d}z = \frac{4}{9}\,h^3(t) + 4\sqrt{3}\,h^2(t) + 36\,h(t)
$$

from which:

$$
V'(t) = \frac{4}{3}\,h^2(t)\,h'(t) + 8\sqrt{3}\,h(t)\,h'(t) + 36\,h'(t)
$$

i.e.:

$$
h'(t) = \frac{3\,V'(t)}{4\left(3\sqrt{3}+h(t)\right)^2} = \frac{9}{\left(3\sqrt{3}+h(t)\right)^2}\,.
$$

To calculate $h'(3)$ we need to know $h(3)$ which can be determined by solving the equation:

$$
V(3) = V'(3)\cdot 3 = 36
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\frac{4}{9}\,h^3(3) + 4\sqrt{3}\,h^2(3) + 36\,h(3) = 36
$$

that is, setting for simplicity $h(3) \equiv x$, we have to solve the cubic equation:

$$
x^3 + 9\sqrt{3}\,x^2 + 81\,x - 81 = 0.
$$

Although the roots of polynomials up to the fourth degree can always be expressed by radicals, at the application level it makes more sense to immediately determine a *numerical approximation*.

In particular, being:

$$
f(x) = x^3 + 9\sqrt{3}\,x^2 + 81\,x - 81
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
f'(x) = 3\,x^2 + 18\,\sqrt{3}\,x + 81
$$

if $x_0 = 1$ is reasonably the root of the first attempt, for the **Newton-Raphson method** we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} \approx 0.855974\,; \\
& x_2 = x_1 - \frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)} \approx 0.852492\,; \\
& x_3 = x_2 - \frac{f(x_2)}{f'(x_2)} \approx \underbrace{0.852490}_{h(3)}\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

and here we stop, as at least the first three decimal digits have stabilized, as required!

In conclusion, we have:

$$
h'(3) = \frac{9}{\left(3\sqrt{3}+h(3)\right)^2} \approx \boxed{0.246\,cm/s}.
$$

---

**ADD BONUS** - Wanting to avoid numerical approximations at all costs:

$$
x^3 + 9\sqrt{3}\,x^2 + 81\,x - 81 = 0
$$

the general idea is to reduce to a depressed cubic equation of the quadratic term:

$$
x \mapsto y - \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

that is, by substitution and simplifying we arrive at the equation:

$$
y^3 - 81\sqrt{3} - 81 = 0
$$

where, unexpectedly, the linear term has also disappeared; very lucky! ^_^

It's thanks to this stroke of luck that we can do without complex numbers, in fact:

$$
y = 3\sqrt[3]{3\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
x = 3\sqrt[3]{3\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)}-3\sqrt{3}
$$

so the exact answer to the question is:

$$
h'(3) = \frac{9}{\left(3\sqrt{3}+h(3)\right)^2} = \boxed{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\left(3+3\sqrt{3}\right)^2}} \approx 0.246\,cm/s}.
$$

Obviously this happens because wanted by the author, otherwise not even in dreams! ^_*

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been so helpful, thank you for laying it out so well.